# Differences between ShortcutInfo and ShortcutInfoCompat?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-7.1-nougat, android-appshortcut

What is the real difference of using one or the other, to create a link?

I would like to understand if it depends only on the version is Android or not?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the Compat suffix signifies the backward compatibility of that class. As new features are added in new APIs, a gap is created whereby the older android versions can't have access to those features. This is where Compat classes come in, to make sure that any class that extends them can provide that compatibility even when run in an older device that uses an older API.